# How to understand multi-label classification results in Keras/TF

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a dataset. I have 5 classes. I have built a model and ran it. But, i am not able to get a hold on the results and how to evaluate them meaningfully.

These are the last few likes of my code.

i am getting predictions which seems to be abnormally small. I am not sure how to draw or convert them in meaningful format.
These are my predictions corresponding to the test data.

```
y_pred[24]
array([9.05e-01, 8.39e-02, 3.59e-01, 3.01e-04, 8.53e-01], dtype=float32)

y_test[24]
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

```
model.add(Dense(5,kernel_initializer='normal', activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
                #loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                   optimizer = 'adam',
                metrics=['acc',f1_m,precision_m, recall_m])
```

```
loss, accuracy, f1_score, precision, recall = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print(loss, accuracy, f1_score, precision, recall)
>>>0.33152061700820923 0.6463245749473572 0.7187454700469971 0.7747973203659058 0.6726323366165161
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is to post questions about implementing the algorithms in code, not for general questions about ML. Search in for your answer in the [AI channel](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) or [data science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning). In short though, the output is not "abnormally small", it outputs the probabilities of an example belonging to each class, so all the values will be between 0 and 1. You might be confused by the scientific notation

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me towards these channels. I'll look for a solution there. It helps a lot. I have realized that struggling alone takes me nowhere. People like you can point in the right direction in a snap. :)